# Creating lists with loops by an user in C#

Tags: c#, windows

So I want to make a list of names. I want this list to go on until user inputs 0 to quit, after user types 0 I want all names to be displayed. You probably see what I'm trying to do from the code below...that "typedName" is there just so you see what I'm trying to do.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> names = new List<string>();
            Console.WriteLine("Type in 0 to end.");
            bool over = false;

            while (over != true)
            {
                names.Add(Console.ReadLine());

                if(typedName == "0")
                {
                    over = true;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Entered names : ");
            names.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you tried actually setting that variable to something?

Comment: Learn about the `break` statement or `do while` loop.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.  Right now, it seems like you're just showing us your code.  What is the issue?

Comment: `You probably see what I'm trying to do from the code below` ... that doesn't mean you shouldn't describe what you are trying to do and what your issue is in english.

Comment: Marcel check the answer

Answer (score 4):

First you need the typedName to be captured and then check if it is equal to **`0`**.
if it is not add it to the list

```
    List<string> names = new List<string>();
    Console.WriteLine("Type in 0 to end.");
    while (true)
    {
        var typedName = Console.ReadLine();
        if (typedName.Equals("0"))
        {
            break;
        }
        names.Add(typedName);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Entered names : ");
    foreach(var name in names)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Looks good, but you probably don't want to add the name if it's equal to "0".

Comment: @AndrewBriggs ok modified

Comment: The `over` variable is never modified, the loop could be simplified to `while (true)` and remove that variable entirely.

Comment: I would recommend using `typedName.Equals("0")` instead of `=`

Answer (score 1):

> `if(typedName == "0")`

Well, what is `typedName`?  Or what *should* it be?  I suspect it should be the input entered by the user, something like this:

```
var typedName = Console.ReadLine();
```

You can then add it to the list by using that variable:

```
names.Add(typedName);
```

And compare it with `"0"` as you already do, etc.

Answer (score 0):

your code is not complete  that is why is not working...

you are missing the most important part:

populate the list if and only if  `typedName != "0"`

```
while (!over)
{
    var typedName =Console.ReadLine();
    if(typedName == "0")
    {
        over = true;
    }else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a  name... ");
        names.Add(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    ...
}
```